# MySQL UPDATE with WHERE AND

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

```
if ('$o1s' == 1) {
    $ocode = 1;
    $query6 = "UPDATE `offer_det` SET `ocode`='$ocode' WHERE `fname`='$fname' AND `lname`='$lname'";
           $result6 = mysql_query($query6)or die(mysql_error()); 
}
```

$o1s is a radio select, essentially 1 = selected, 0 = not selected.  ocode is the row in the database to be updated.  $fname is the first name of the logged in user and $lname is the last name of the logged in user.

My thought process is if o1s is selected then update ocode to 1 where the first and last names match.  I'm not seeing any action on the results though.  This is a session post form.  Can I even use the AND during an UPDATE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line needs to be like this,

```
if ($o1s == 1) { //checking a variable, not a string with a '$'
```

Also, check the `$_POST` array for the corresponding value of `o1s` when its selected and not, you would have to put an `isset` check when its not. And yes, you can use `AND` for an `update`

Comment: Thanks buddy.  I'm trying to learn this and I'm hoping to switch over to OO MySQLi next week.

Comment: Hm, I'm still not seeing any action on this.  The form will post no problem but no data is being updated.  There's gotta be something wrong with my post statement. 

$o1s = $_POST['o1s'];

Comment: A select tag eg. `<select id="select" name="o1s"><option value='1'/></select>` would give `$_POST['o1s'] = '1'` when option 1 is selected. If its not selected, there won't be any key set for `o1s` in $_POST.  Do a `var_dump` on the $_POST to see, if you are getting the desired value when its selected and not.

Comment: Ya ended up having to have a isset to get the MySQL UPDATE to run.  Thanks for the assistance, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You do compare the string '$os1' with 1.

This will always fail.

Remove the ' and it will work.

e.g.

```
if($os1==1) //this will pass if $os1 equals the number 1

if('$os1'==1) // this will never pass cause
              // you compare the string "$os1" with the integer number 1
```